# Adding a computed column that uses MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a sequential number column for record number proposes

I am OK with losing sequence if I delete a row from the middle of the table
For example
1
2
3

If I delete 2, I am ok with new column been 4.

I tried to alter my table to

```
alter table [dbo].[mytable]
add [record_seq] as (MAX(record_seq) + 1)
```

but I am getting `An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint`.

Which is a bit confusing? do I need to specify an initial value? is there a better way?

Comment: That's not MySQL syntax, it looks like SQL-Server.

Comment: Why is the message confusing? `MAX()` is an aggregate function, it's not allowed in computed columns.

Comment: why isn't it allowed? how do you do that if not with max?

Comment: You said, "I need to create a sequential number column for record number proposes"... What's wrong with an identity column? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: How can the value of the computed column be based on itself?

Comment: Remember, a computed column is in every row. How can all the rows have `record_seq` that's equal to the max+1 of all of them? You get an infinite regress.

Comment: Sample and expected output would help.

Comment: @xQbert isn't ID not sequential? if a transaction fails it increments

Comment: sure; but that's just a gap; just like a delete... The next number would be used 1,2,3, fail,5,6,deleted,7,8,9...  so it's still in sequence...  additionally say your table is empty to start with ... Max+1 gives you what NULL?... Also depending on the order of execution under volume; max+1 may not be in sequence...

Comment: I cannot have gaps for failure , that is why I am trying to do this.

1,2,3 -> fail, next should be 4

Comment: Seems like a major X Y problem here. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Because a computed column does not appear to either a) fit your requirements nor b) even have the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Having a record number for entry that will not skip on failure

if you have rec1, rec2, rec3

and you decided to delete rec2, it makes sense to skip 2 because it will tell you it was deleted. But if you failed at an insert you still want to see 4, because 4 was never created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to allocate a sequence number even in cases where the table doesn't get a record inserted, I would handle it in the process responsible for performing those inserts. Create another table, in this table keep track of the max identity value of that sequence. Each time you want to perform an insert, reserve the sequence number you want by updating that table first. If you rely on selecting the max existing value, you could be at risk of multiple sessions getting the same "new" sequence number before inserting. Even if the insert fails, you will have incremented that control table so nothing else uses that value that has been reserved.

Comment: And this differs from what an identity would do identity how?

Answer (score 1):

Its not supported in MsSql. You can use identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE  [dbo].[mytable]
ADD [record_seq] INT IDENTITY
```

Or use trigger to update your seq column after insert and/or delete

Comment: this won't keep sequence on failure

Comment: trigger, which calculates MAX(ID), would always assign next. And I think IDENTITY would also.